# How to apply faceted search in elastic search with multiple filters?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, lucene

```
{
   path: '/xyz.com/electronics/1',
   body: {
        category: 'mobiles',
        product: 'apple iphone 6',
        brand: 'apple',
        mobile_name: 'iphone 6',
        price: 55000,
        os: undefined,
        memory: 16,
        ram: 2,
        3g: 1,
        wifi: 1,
        simtype: 1,
        screen: 5.1
   },
   query: {}
}
```

Above given is a record of my elastic search index. I am trying to apply multiple filters on it depending upon what user requests for
for ex price range between 2000-5000, wifi value 1, screen above 5 inches etc.

I tried this:

```
client.search({
    index: "xyz.com",
    type: 'electronics',
    body: {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "mobiles"
            }
        },
        "facets": {
            "format": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "brand"
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

How can I write a generic query for such filters?

Comment: Instead of using a query_string, simply use a [filtered](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) query and add the filters you need ( e.g. price between 2000-2500 => [range](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-range-filter.html) filter, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Thomas, you can use filtered queries.

Consider these four documents (index facets, type doc):

```
PUT facets/doc/1
{
  "name":"doc1",
  "user":"archer",
  "tag":"elasticsearch"
}
PUT facets/doc/2
{
  "name":"doc2",
  "user":"betty",
  "tag":["solr"]
}
PUT facets/doc/3
{
  "name":"doc3",
  "user":"cyril",
  "tag":["elasticsearch", "solr"]
}
PUT facets/doc/4
{
  "name":"doc4",
  "user":"lena",
  "tag":["java","solr"]
}
```

You can get the tag and user facets using this aggregation query (note that [facet queries are deprecated](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-facets.html)):

```
GET facets/_search
{
"aggs": { 
   "agg_user": {
      "terms": {
         "field": "user"
      }
   },
   "agg_tag": {
      "terms": {
         "field": "tag"
      }
   }
  }
}
```

Then you can [filter by a specific user and a specific tag](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#_multiple_filters):

```
GET facets/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"term": { "tag": "solr" }},
            {"term": { "user": "betty" }}
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
"aggs": { 
   "agg_user": {
      "terms": {
         "field": "user"
      }
   },
   "agg_tag": {
      "terms": {
         "field": "tag"
      }
   }
  }
}
```

You can read more about facet-based drill down for example here: http://distinctplace.com/2014/07/29/build-zappos-like-products-facets-with-elasticsearch/

(the above snippets are Marvel Sense scripts)